# Min Stack Solution Error with Top Method?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

[Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/min-stack/)

My output for the input

```
["MinStack","push","push","push","getMin","pop","top","getMin"]
[[],[-2],[0],[-3],[],[],[],[]]
```

is

```
[null,null,null,null,-3,null,-3,-2]
```

whereas the expected is

```
[null,null,null,null,-3,null,0,-2]
```

I expect the `"top"` method is where my problem is but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Can someone point it out for me? I am using two stacks to solve the problem. One stack to push the inputs and a minStack that the inputs get pushed into by comparing its values to the values of the first stack.

```
/**
 * initialize your data structure here.
 */
let MinStack = function() {
  this.stack = new Stack();
  this.minStack = new Stack();
};

/** 
 * @param {number} x
 * @return {void}
 */
MinStack.prototype.push = function(x) {
  this.stack.push(x);
  if (this.minStack.size === 0) {
    this.minStack.push(x);
  } else if (x <= this.minStack.peek()) {
    this.minStack.push(x);
  }
};

/**
 * @return {void}
 */
MinStack.prototype.pop = function() {
  let popped = this.stack.peek();
  if (popped === this.minStack.peek()) {
    this.minStack.pop()
  }
};

/**
 * @return {number}
 */ 
MinStack.prototype.top = function() {
  return this.stack.peek();
};

/**
 * @return {number}
 */
MinStack.prototype.getMin = function() {
  return this.minStack.peek();
};

class Stack {
  constructor() {
    this.storage = {};
    this.size = 0;
  }
  push(val) {
    this.storage[this.size] = val;
    this.size++;
  }
  pop() {
    let top = this.storage[this.size - 1];
    delete this.storage[this.size - 1];
    this.size--;
    return top;
  }
  peek() {
    return this.storage[this.size - 1];
  }
  getSize() {
    return this.size;
  }
  empty() {
    return this.size === 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question!

Not sure about your bug, we can just use the JavaScript array for this problem. This'll pass just fine:

```
var MinStack = function() {
    this.stack = [];
};

MinStack.prototype.push = function(x) {
    this.stack.push({
        value: x,
        min: this.stack.length === 0 ? x : Math.min(x, this.getMin()),
    });
};


MinStack.prototype.pop = function() {
    this.stack.pop();
};

MinStack.prototype.top = function() {
    return this.stack[this.stack.length - 1].value;
};

MinStack.prototype.getMin = function() {
    return this.stack[this.stack.length - 1].min;
};
```

If you like to use your own `Stack()`, plug it in the above code here:

```
this.stack = [];
```

and it should work fine. For that you're gonna have to write a `min()` method and I guess it would go like:

```
class MyOwnMinStack {
    constructor() {
        this.storage = {};
        this.size = 0;
        this.currMin = null
    }
    push(val) {
        this.storage[this.size] = val;
        this.size++;
    }
    pop() {
        let top = this.storage[this.size - 1];
        delete this.storage[this.size - 1];
        this.size--;
        return top;
    }
    peek() {
        return this.storage[this.size - 1];
    }
    getSize() {
        return this.size;
    }
    empty() {
        return this.size === 0;
    }
    min() {
        // To do
        return this.currMin;
    }
}
```

Every time we would `push()` or `pop()`, we'd keep track of `this.currMin`, such that we'd return it at constant time complexity `O(1)` once `min()` is called.

---

Here, I'll copy some other ways to solve the problem with other languages, might help you to figure it out. For example, this [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) method uses two stacks:

```
class MinStack {
private:
    stack<int> stack_one;
    stack<int> stack_two;

public:
    void push(int x) {
        stack_one.push(x);
        if (stack_two.empty() || x <= getMin())
            stack_two.push(x);
    }

    void pop() {
        if (stack_one.top() == getMin())
            stack_two.pop();

        stack_one.pop();
    }

    int top() {
        return stack_one.top();
    }

    int getMin() {
        return stack_two.top();
    }
};
```

#### Python

```
class MinStack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = [(float('inf'), float('inf'))]

    def push(self, x):
        self.stack.append((x, min(x, self.stack[-1][1])))

    def pop(self):
        if len(self.stack) > 1:
            self.stack.pop()

    def top(self):
        if len(self.stack) > 1:
            return self.stack[-1][0]
        return

    def getMin(self):
        if len(self.stack) > 1:
            return self.stack[-1][1]
        return
```

#### Java

```
class MinStack {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    public void push(int x) {
        if (x <= min) {
            stack.push(min);
            min = x;
        }
        stack.push(x);
    }

    public void pop() {
        if (stack.pop() == min)
            min = stack.pop();
    }

    public int top() {
        return stack.peek();
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/min-stack/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.